# How can i resolve the error "Line 1: The type XX cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" in GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, reference

I've got one **Maven GWT application** and it's throwing the error you can see in the title.
When i start my gwt project via eclipse everything works. The site will be loaded and "**it's compiling**". But after several seconds there is a failure.(Picture 1)

How can i solve it?

Restarting eclipse, erasing dependencies and add them again, erasing JRE or JDK and add them again etc.. does not work :'(

**Important:** This project is uploaded on a subversion server. My partner here at work can check the project out but does not receive this kind of failure.

I'm using Eclipse Mars 2 and work on a Windows 7 64-bit operating system

[image: The site of my application]

---

Hello I'm [KilledByCheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6603725/killedbycheese) his Coworker - I didn't changed anything in the POM or on the BuildPath ... but i took a loog at the Console output of my colleague:

```
Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.place.rebind.PlaceHistoryMapperGenerator'/>
              Tracing compile failure path for type 'x.z.y.client.SearchActivity.EditorFramework'
              [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
     [ERROR] Errors in 'x/y/z/client/SearchActivity.java'
        [ERROR] Line 71: Failed to resolve 'x.y.z.client.SearchActivity.EditorFramework' via deferred binding
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have an obsolete class file somewhere. Maven will not recompile classes if it thinks they are up-to-date but sometimes Maven gets confused. Try doing a Maven clean.

On the other hand, it could be that Maven is right and Eclipse got it wrong when it thinks there is no problem. In that case you could try Project -> Clean.

A third alternative is the the error is genuine, and that your colleague changed the build path in Eclipse without updating the pom.